# static method from abstract class

Tags: java

i have abstract class Figures and 2 inheritors. Triangle, Square and Rectangle.
I need to create a static method which will use the array of figures and return the sum of their areas.

```
abstract class Figure {

abstract double calculatePerimeter();

    abstract double calculateArea()
```

```
public class Rectangle extends Figure {
    double a;
    double b;

    public Rectangle(double a, double b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    double calculatePerimeter() {
        return 2 * (a + b);
    }

    @Override
    double calculateArea() {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

```
public class Triangle extends Figure {
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;

    public Triangle(double a, double b, double c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    double calculatePerimeter() {
        return a + b + c;
    }

    @Override
    double calculateArea() {
        double p = calculatePerimeter() / 2.0;
        return Math.sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c));
    }
```

So I should create a list of figures and use in in the method, but it doesn't work

```
Figure[] figures=new Figure[3];
figures[1]=new Square(4.6);
figures[2]=new Rectangle(4.5,5.2);
figures[3]=new Triangle(6,5,2.2);
```

```
 public static double findSquare(????????) {
        return square.calculateArea() + rectangle.calculateArea() + triangle.calculateArea();
```

How should it work and which topic should i read?
Please explain

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: I guess this is something you are looking for? https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_inheritance.asp

Comment: attention this `figures[3]=new Triangle(6,5,2.2);` will throw exception... first index is zero.

Comment: I need to create a static method which will use the array of figures and return the sum of their areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use inheritance and you implement `calculateArea` on every sub-figure (square, rectangle, triangle), all you have to do is iterate over the array of figures and sum the `calculateArea` on all the figures:

```
public static double findSquare(Figure[] arr) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i : arr) { 
        sum = sum + arr[i].calculateArea();
    }
    return sum;
```

Note: I really think you should read and understand how to work with [Java Inheritance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-java/) and with [Arrays](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

You shoud loop/stream on the array then map each element to area value by calling polymorphic method `calculateArea` and finally make the sum.

Example with java streams :

`double sumOfArea = Arrays.stream(arrayOfFigure).mapToDouble(Figure::calculateArea).sum()`